# Exclude IP from OpenVPN route

Tags: openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server, and would like to make clients route an address range, like `1.2.3.0/24` through VPN. However, I do NOT want to make clients use VPN for a specific IP address *on that same range*. So the routing table on the clients should look like this:

`1.2.3.4/32` - through client's default gateway
`1.2.3.0/24` - through VPN

I added the following to my server.conf:

```
push "route 1.2.3.0 255.255.255.0"
```

However, this will route `1.2.3.4` through VPN as well. Is there any way to solve this with OpenVPN server config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a more specific route for the IP address that you don't want to go through the VPN and use the `net_gateway` and `vpn_gateway` options to specify the gateway for the route.

```
push "route 1.2.3.4 255.255.255.255 net_gateway"
push "route 1.2.3.0 255.255.255.0 vpn_gateway"
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate this Answer.? I am blocked at similar situation, where i am using a OpenVPN Community edition. I am not sure on the net_gateway and vpn_gateway how it has to be referenced in server.conf file. I am getting below error when i tried adding a specific route to be excluded.

2022-03-16 17:03:34 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 1.2.3.4 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.13
2022-03-16 17:03:34 ROUTE: route addition failed using service: The parameter is incorrect.   [status=87 if_index=24]
2022-03-16 17:03:34 Route addition via service failed

Comment: The lines in my answer go into your server.conf file. Replace `1.2.3.4 255.255.255.255` and `1.2.3.0 255.255.255.0` with the subnets you want to be routed via the usual gateway or through the VPN.

Comment: I still continue to get the error "ROUTE: route addition failed using service: The parameter is incorrect.   [status=87 if_index=24]" when tried connecting from my windows machine through OpenVPN GUI client. the problem is that push "route 168.127.3.4 255.255.255.0" the 4th block is not getting added to the route @ilikeMUDs any suggestion.?